# How to set duplicate value validation in sequence diagram?

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I'm using the boundary-control-entity model for my sequence diagram, but in the alt fragment I'm confused about the interactions between the control and the entity in case the entity I'm adding contains duplicated fields.
shoudl I put select() before entering the alt fragment to show that the control is checking whether the informations are duplicated or no ?

My diagram:
5.Select() is the message I'm asking about
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct that way. The test condition is executed first. The alt fragment evaluates the existing conditions via the guards. These guards can contain anything and relate to something that happened any time (and not only directly) before.

Personal note: graphical programming is not really the silver bullet as it was praised in the 90s. SDs are fine to give an overview of collaborating objects. But when you try to go into details (like when using fragments) you soon recognize its shortcomings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using this method because I'm working on a graduation project and that's the type of sequence diagram we're asked to do on our report.

Comment: Most questions here are from lectures :-) Just keep in mind what I said (except you find it 's the best thing since sliced bread).

Comment: Actually I didn't understand your advice, but I'm using springBoot for the backend and angular for the frontend so I guess It's not graphical programming. The thing is we're asked to to that type of diagrams (boundary-control-entity) that's why I was confused ..

Comment: My advise is: Avoid fragments and only use them where it can't be avoided. Don't start graphical programming. Since it will eat up much of your time. In parctice I would just use a note to describe the error case.

Comment: I got it, by graphical programming you meant the fragments in the diagram and getting into too much details. Thank you for the advice :D

Comment: Exactly. When I started studying IT in the mid 70s it was praised as the future of programming (not UML, but graphical programming). Turned out, it's ok for kids, but any little more than trivial behavior can not be handled that way,